# What are the available attributes in the attribute node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

What are **All** the attributes I can access through the attribute node. I know of a few like density, flame, a UV map etc, but I'm curious as to what else there is.

Comment: Custom properties are not accessible D:

Comment: The wiki says that internal attributes are also available. Those include, but are not limited to, N (normal), P (position) and Ng (Geometry Normal)

Comment: @gandalf3 I even looked.... I can't believe I missed that.